# replace id to value in group by query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
order_to_service(
id,
order_id,
service_id

);
service(
 id,
 name

);
```

What i want is - select the most popular services from this table, my query:

```
 select service_id ,count(order_id)  from order_to_service  group by service_id
```

I have the following output:

```
6;9
4;124
1;40
2;37
```

now i want replace service id to service name to have the following output:

```
wash;9
wifi;124
pc;40
juice;37
```

How to update my first query to has such output?

Comment: Which table has the service name, and what is this column called?

Comment: You need to join to the table that contains that information

Comment: service table contains the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is a `service` table with a `name` column, then a simple join should work:

```
select
    s.name,
    count(o.order_id)
from order_to_service o
inner join service s
    on o.service_id = s.id
group by
    o.service_id,
    s.name;
```

I group by both the service id and name because perhaps names are not unique.  But the combination of a service id and a name should be unique.